# Creating nested JSON objects with different formats in Java with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm 100% certain this has been asked a million times already, but I'm really unsure how to properly approach this. I haven't done a lot with JSON or serializing it yet.

Basically, this is what I want to create using GSON:

```
{
    "wrapper" : [
        {
            "content": "loremipsum",
            "positions": [0,3]
        },
        {
            "content": "foobar",
            "positions": [7]
        },
        {
            "content": "helloworld"
        }
    ]
}
```

Breaking it down, we've got a field for an array, containing objects which in themselves contains two fields, one of which maps to a string and the other to yet another array that can contain an unknown amount of integers or can be missing entirely.

I can't even begin to imagine how to get this result with GSON. So far my idea would be to have everything be in a `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>` beast and convert it, but that Object bothers me because it could either be a String or a List in this particular case. There could be casts, but that sounds like a stupidy complex thing for something that would look easier if I even just manually typed it in a String.format() or similar.

Isn't there a simpler way of handling this stuff?

Comment: you can just use this two pojo:  ´class Wrapper { public String content; public List<Integer> positions}´ and ´class Response { public List<Wrapper> wrapper}´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with creating some POJO class for your Data :

```
class MyData {
    private List<Data> wrapper;

    //getters setters constructors
}

class Data {
    private String content;
    private List<Integer> positions;

    //getters setters constructors
}
```

And then for deserializing it :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = //json here
MyData myData = gson.fromJson(myJson, MyData.class);
```

And for serializing :

```
MyData myData = ...
String json = gson.toJson(myData);
```

Another way could be parsing this structure using [`JsonParser`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) and access its elements :

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json);
JsonElement wrapperElement = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("wrapper"); //access wrapper
JsonArray array = wrapperElement.getAsJsonArray(); // access array
```

Comment: That's a lot of boilerplate... I don't need JSON anywhere else in the program, not sure if that's the best approach here. But it should work for a start!

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. For me working with POJO models in easier. Another approach would be to use `JsonElement` objects and traverse it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Pojo for formatting.

```
class Wrapper{
 private List<Data> data;
 // geters, seters
}
class Data{
 private String content;
 private List<Integer> positions;
 // geters, seters
}
```

For deserialization/serealization you can use [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper wriper = mapper.readValue(dataString, Wrapper.class);
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(wriper);
```

or [Gson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Wrapper wriper = gson.fromJson(dataString, Wrapper.class);
String json = gson.toJson(wriper);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gson JsonElement as the contianer object that will contain  JsonElements like JsonObject or JsonArray

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Answer (score 0):

Without POJO, this seems to solve the nested JSON solution using Gson

```
package com.test;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JsonObject ex3 = new JsonObject();
        ex3.addProperty("example3", 30);
        
        JsonObject ex2 = new JsonObject();  
        ex2.add("example2", ex3.getAsJsonObject());
        
        JsonObject ex1 = new JsonObject();  
        ex1.add("example1", ex2.getAsJsonObject());
        
        System.out.println(ex1.toString());
    }       
}
```

The output is:

```
{"example1":{"example2":{"example3":30}}}
```